# Better way of adding multilingual on webpage

Tags: javascript, multilingual

Does anyone can suggest what is better way of adding multilingual feature on webpage? I have created mine by calling my JavaScript function. This is how came up. In my "home.html" I created select tag:

```
    <select id="nav-lang" onchange="onChangeLang()">
             <option value="en">English</option>
             <option value="ch">中文</option>
             <option value="in">हिंदी</option>
    </select>
```

and on my JavaScript function this is what I did:

```
    function onChangeLang(){
          var lang = document.getElementById("nav-lang").value;
          if(lang=="ch"){
                 //I target all id in my div and set all innerHTML text to its equivalent chinese term
           }else if(lang=="in"){
                 //Same with I did in Chinese, however it is on India
          }else{
                //switch to English ex. document.getElementById("home"). innerHTML = "Home";
          }
    }
```

What can you suggest to make it better? Actually I am thinking of having copies of my pages written on different languages but I don't think it's a good idea. Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing any backend code, or is it only plain HTML and Javascript?

Comment: Only Html and JavaScript sir.

Answer (score 1):

https://davidwalsh.name/google-translate-api
I found a good tutorial for you about how to use the google translate Api in JavaScript. You can find it by clicking the link above.
Hope I helped ya! :)

Comment: Thanks sir I should try it also.